# How to change position of an element in an array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

If I have an array, for example this

```
Dim Players() As String = {"Adam", "Helen", "Jack", "Emily"}
```

How do I change the position of each element by a value, for example if by 1, `Adam` will move to 2, `Helen` will move to 3, and `Emily` should come back to 1.

I was able to do this if increment by 1. I would have the last element stored in a variable and when done moving all elements by 1, I would set the first element to the variable(Emily in this case).

How would I do it if having different increment values like 2, 3, 4, or even 6?

**Edit:** Any programming language is fine but it has to be done with for loops and no functions.

**Update:** I am an IGCSE student and this question is bugging from over a week.

Comment: Visual Basic and C++ have almost nothing in common.

Comment: [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: It would be preferable if you read [ask], took the [tour], and showed some effort to solve this.  A Swap is a pretty simple, fundamental programming tasl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do an increment of one, just repeat that the required number of times.

A better way would be: (let's call the increment *n*); store the end *n* elements in another array; move the elements before that towards the end of the array; copy back the elements from the other array to the start. Like this:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim players() As String = {"Adam", "Becky", "Clive", "Debby", "Edward", "Fiona"}
        Dim rotateBy = 2

        ' make sure shiftBy is in a usable range
        rotateBy = rotateBy Mod players.Length
        ' if shiftBy is negative, make it positive such that a left-rotate is performed
        If rotateBy < 0 Then
            rotateBy = rotateBy + players.Length
        End If

        ' store the elements which will be moved to the other end of the array
        Dim tmp(rotateBy - 1) As String
        Dim startIndex = players.Length - rotateBy
        For i = startIndex To players.Length - 1
            tmp(i - startIndex) = players(i)
        Next

        ' move the elements
        For i = players.Length - 1 - rotateBy To 0 Step -1
            players(i + rotateBy) = players(i)
        Next

        'fill in the other elements
        For i = 0 To rotateBy - 1
            players(i) = tmp(i)
        Next

        ' show the result
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", players))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Note that the copying of elements within the `players` array is done backwards so that an overlapping range does not splat over values which have yet to be moved.

To shift the elements backwards, use a negative value for `rotateBy`.

If you are using a language with a function which gives array copying functions, this method is easy to adapt to use that functionality. For anyone wondering about that in the future:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim players() As String = {"Adam", "Becky", "Clive", "Debby", "Edward", "Fiona"}
        Dim rotateBy = 4

        ' make sure shiftBy is in a usable range
        rotateBy = rotateBy Mod players.Length
        ' if shiftBy is negative, make it positive such that a left-rotate is performed
        If rotateBy < 0 Then
            rotateBy = rotateBy + players.Length
        End If

        ' store the elements which will be moved to the other end of the array
        Dim tmp(rotateBy - 1) As String
        Dim startIndex = players.Length - rotateBy

        Array.Copy(players, startIndex, tmp, 0, rotateBy)
        Array.Copy(players, 0, players, rotateBy, startIndex)
        Array.Copy(tmp, players, tmp.Length)

        ' show the result
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", players))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

---

As you mentioned *any* programming language, this is what it could be in C# as a function but without using any framework methods such as `Array.Copy`:

```
public static void RotateUsingLoops<T>(T[] elements, int rotateBy)
{
    rotateBy = rotateBy % elements.Length;
    if (rotateBy < 0)
    {
        rotateBy += elements.Length;
    }
    T[] tmp = new T[rotateBy];
    int startIndex = elements.Length - rotateBy;

    // store the elements which will be moved to the other end of the array
    for (int i = startIndex; i < elements.Length; i++)
    {
        tmp[i - startIndex] = elements[i];
    }

    // move the elements
    for (int i = elements.Length - 1 - rotateBy; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        elements[i + rotateBy] = elements[i];
    }

    // fill in the other elements
    for (int i = 0; i < rotateBy; i++)
    {
        elements[i] = tmp[i];
    }
}
```

Whereby you could use

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    RotateUsingLoops(a, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a));

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

to get an output of:

> C, D, A, B

Answer (score 0):

Circular array rotation is what you are referring towards.

In VB.NET the following code will rotate an array of elements to the Right, by the Shift amount.

```vb
Sub Main()

    Dim Players() As String = {"Adam", "Helen", "Jack", "Emily"}

    Dim Players_Shifted(Players.Length - 1) As String

    Dim Shift As Integer = 2
    If Shift > Players.Length Then
        Shift = Shift Mod Players.Length
    End If

    For index = 0 To Shift - 1
        Players_Shifted(index) = Players(Players.Length - Shift + index)
    Next

    Dim index_2 = 0
    For index = Shift To Players.Length - 1
        Players_Shifted(index) = Players(index_2)
        index_2 = index_2 + 1
    Next
    Players = Players_Shifted


    ' Print out Players Array '

    For index = 0 To Players.Length - 1
        Console.Write(Players(index) + ", ")
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a snippet of a C++ code that implements this functionality-

Let temp be a temporary variable, N be the size of the array, shift be the number of places u wanna shift and *arr* be the original array.

```
int temp = arr[0];
int i = 0;
while(True){
    //swap(arr(i + shift)%N, temp);
    swap_var = temp;
    temp = arr[(i+shift)%N];
    arr[(i+shift)%N] = swap_var;

    i = (i+shift)%N;
    if (i == 0){
        break;
    }
}
```

Edit: Using for loop.

```
int temp = arr[0];       //change int to the type of variable ur array is
int i =0;
for (int count = 0; count<N ; count++){
    //swap(arr(i + shift)%N, temp);
    swap_var = temp;
    temp = arr[(i+shift)%N];
    arr[(i+shift)%N] = swap_var;

    i = (i+shift)%N;
}
```

Comment: The question specified the use of for loops.

Comment: Andrew,  the mentioning of for loop is in the edit section after I posted this answer.

Comment: 1) It's always a nuisance when that happens. 2) I think you got a downvote from someone because of the line `temp = arr[0];` - you forgot to reassign `temp` in the loop - did you *test* your code for values of `shift` other than 1?

Comment: Andrew , There is a swap function which updates temp every time.Though I have not provided the code for the swap function.

Comment: That is essential information which should have been included in your answer ;) But that edit I was referring to earlier also states "no functions".

Comment: Andrew I have added that swap functionality as an edit.