# vb.net order list by certain index

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, sorting

i have a list of integers (0,1,2)
i want to reorder the list but using a certain index:
if i choose 1 i want to get (1,2,0)
if i choose 2 i want to get (2,0,1)

i created a list then tried to order it by the index but i get undesired results!

```
Dim ind As New List(Of Integer) 
For l = 0 To n : ind.Add(l) : Next

Dim start As List(Of Integer) = ind.OrderBy(Function(v) v = index).ToList()
```

if i use 0 i get 1,2,0
if i use 1 i get 0,2,1!
if i use 2 i get 0,1,2!

Comment: What you describe as "reorder the list but using a certain index" is normally known as rotating the array. E.g. [How to change position of an element in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42459522/1115360)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to sort if you just need to rotate/shift the list by taking the elements starting from certain index and then appending the rest of the elements after. For example:

```
Dim A = {3, 6, 9}, L = A.Length, N = 2

Debug.Print(String.Join(",", A.Skip(N).Concat(A.Take(N)))) ' "9,3,6"

Debug.Print(String.Join(",", From i In Enumerable.Range(N, L) Select A(i Mod L))) ' "9,3,6"
```

Sorting them might work in most cases but probably not all:

```
Debug.Print(String.Join(",", From e In A Order By e < A(N))) ' "9,3,6"
```

Generating the list directly without shifting or sorting might be possible too:

```
Debug.Print(String.Join(",", From i In Enumerable.Range(N, L) Select i Mod L)) ' "2,0,1"
```

Comment: thanks, that solved it, it has been few days thinking of how to shift it.